# Best way to represent 1/3rd of 100% in CSS?

Tags: css

I have a big `<div>` with three little `<div>`'s inside of it, inline. They each have 33% width, but that causes some alignment problems because 3 * 33% != 100%. What is the best way to represent a perfect third in CSS like this? Maybe just 33.33%?

Comment: Just throw enough decimal places at it until it's unlikely someone has a desktop large enough to make sig.figs relevant to the calculation.

Comment: You can't specify fractions, so 33.33% is pretty much your only option.

Comment: Useful info: [Sub-Pixel Rendering Problems in CSS](http://ejohn.org/blog/sub-pixel-problems-in-css/)

Comment: This is why it would be awesome to count in base 12 rather than in base 10. Half=6, third=4, quarter=3, sixth=2. Two thirds=8, three quarters=9. Base 10 is a pain

Answer (score 138, accepted):

Now that `calc` is [widely supported](http://caniuse.com/calc) among modern browsers, you can use:

```
#myDiv {
    width: calc(100% / 3);
}
```

Or you can use this as a fallback if your browser wouldn't support it:

```
#myDivWithFallback {
    width: 33.33%;
    width: calc(100% / 3);
}
```

Comment: Don't forget the fallback: `.column-one-third { width: 33.33%; width: calc(100%/3); }`. That way you can support non calc browsers.

Comment: I've found that 6 decimal places is often necessary for it to properly calculate the exact 1/3 of a div. `width: 33.333333%;`

Comment: side note, both `calc(200% / 3)` and `calc(100% / 1.5)` work nicely as 2/3rds

Answer (score 15):

Are you making any allowance for margins? You could go 30% per column with 5% margin either side of the center column.

[Quick example](http://jsfiddle.net/Marcel/EXbNX/1/embedded/result/)

Answer (score 8):

```
.col_1_3 {
    width: 33%;
    float: left;
}

.col_1_3:nth-of-type(even) {
    width: 34%;
}
```

Comment: .col_1_3 {width: 33.33%; float: left;} is a better approach. Maybe some box-sizing: border-box and some padding.

Answer (score 7):

The highest resolution screen is [a non-production NEC LCD screen](http://www.tomshardware.com/news/nec-lcd,3660.html) with a resolution of 2800x2100. Even at that size, one pixel is 0.0357% of the width of the screen. So `33.33%` should be close enough until 5,000-pixel-wide screens become the norm.

[John Resig did some research](http://ejohn.org/blog/sub-pixel-problems-in-css/) into sub-pixel rounding in different browsers, though, so depending on your three columns to equal *exactly* the width of the screen may never have a perfect solution.

Comment: That "high" sounds a little low for current non-production monitors. This looks a little more reasonable as a current technology ceiling.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultra_High_Definition_Television

Comment: This answer is not very future proof

Comment: 2021: Writing this comment from my 3840x2160 standard production monitor