# Math in CSS - more precise percentages

Tags: html, css

This is how I make a 3 column page with equal sizes:

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <div style="width:33%;float:left;background-color:red;"></div>
    <div style="width:33%;float:left;background-color:green;"></div>
   <div style="width:33%;float:left;background-color:blue;"></div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to avoid using `width:33%` and entering a more accurate number?
I'm ok with javascript options.

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5158735/best-way-to-represent-1-3rd-of-100-in-css

Comment: I think at `33.33%` the error is less than a pixel.

Comment: 33.33% is enough, no1s going to sit with a magnifying glass and calculate the column widths

Comment: In general, because of rounding errors (and sub-pixel rendering) in the browsers, it's best to specify as much precision as possible. In this case it may not matter, but consider if you also have nested elements that use percentage widths. The errors will compound. [related](https://github.com/nex3/sass/issues/319)

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished using the [CSS3 `calc()` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/calc).

**CSS**:

```
div.column {
    width: 33.33%; /* Fallback in case the browser does not support calc() */
    width: -webkit-calc(100% / 3); /* Chrome 19 and above */
    width:    -moz-calc(100% / 3); /* Firefox 4 and above */
    width:         calc(100% / 3); /* IE 9 and above */
}
```

**HTML**:

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="column" style="float:left;background-color:red;"></div>
   <div class="column" style="float:left;background-color:green;"></div>
   <div class="column" style="float:left;background-color:blue;"></div>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/KjWsa/1/)

[Browser Compatibility Table](http://caniuse.com/calc)

Comment: Good point on the fall-back. I was discounting calc completely for a few more years. shouldn't the fall back be on top though?

Comment: @sheriffderek Good catch, I believe you are right about the fallback position. I changed my answer to reflect that.

Comment: I keep looking for more clarity on this. I mean, you want the preferred one last. So the un-prefixed one - even if it's not in gear yet (for the future) and you want the rgb or #000 above rgba etc... but what is best for the other ones... 

I would think -ms- -0- -moz- -webkit-

Comment: but Paul Irish has -webkit- -moz- -ms- -o- noprefix in that order... which doesn't really make sense to me... but he is kinda the expert... I guess, -webkit- for mobile might be faster if it is first? Mystery #3046

Comment: @sheriffderek The fallback should be first. See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14914822/does-the-placement-of-a-css-property-value-matter-when-it-is-used-as-a-fallback).

Comment: Yes. I was referring to the prefix order.

Comment: the order of the prefixes does not matter. In every case the browser has to parse every declaration in the block and discards the one with the unknown prefixes - that's why the fallback needs to be first and the standard last, the rest is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

First of all - get those styles out of the html:

```
<body>
    <section class="main-content">
        <div class="colum01">Column01</div>
        <div class="colum02">Column01</div>
        <div class="colum02">Column01</div>
    </section>
</body>
```

In your CSS:

```
.main-content {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.column01 {
    width: 33%;
    float: left;
    background-color: red;
}

.column02 {
    width: 34%;
    float: left;
    background-color: orange;
}

.column03 {
    width: 33%;
    float: left;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

or you can use 33.3 and 33.4 and 33.3%

I keep assuming that everyone uses border-box: this is going to make everything magic once you start padding. pushes the padding inside the box instead of outsite, so you don't have to worry about adding up all of the padding and widths to make 100%

[Paul Irish on the subject](http://paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/)

`* { 
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
    box-sizing: border-box; 
    }`

If you are using lists to display things in columns, you can you :nth to target the 3rd item in each column and put a 33.4% on those only... Using calc is not widely supported at this time and using javaScript is still just going to create styles for you. So I would suggest keeping things as simple as possible. This works great for me. (and it gets rid of that pesky little black line that appears when you use 33.3% on all 3.

Comment: (Border box stuff would go near top of your css)

Comment: In most cases 33.333333 --- there seem to be 6 numbers in complex percentages before it repeats... so I've just started doing that as a standard.  or like, [32] [2] [32] [2] [32] with 2% gutters.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you directly use `width:33.33%`? It's not impossible. It's not even particularly hard, with the use of `display: table.` Tables work great if you know your screen size. Responsive tables however are still being worked out

[Compatibility table](http://caniuse.com/css-table) for support of CSS Table display in desktop and mobile browsers. Some IE 7 fixes related to CSS Table are [here](http://tanalin.com/en/projects/display-table-htc/).

Comment: Tables work great if you know your screen size. Responsive tables however are still being worked out.

Comment: I'm assumed you did. It was more of a note for the person who asked the question. :-)