# Does the placement of a CSS property/value matter when it is used as a fallback?

Tags: css, cross-browser

Does the placement of a CSS property/value matter when it is being used as a "fallback" for browsers not compatible with a certain CSS3 property/value?

For example, [the CSS3 `calc()` function only works with certain browsers](http://caniuse.com/calc). Let's say I want to have a div whose width is 1/3 its parent. I could use `width:calc(100%/3)` to achieve this with browsers that are `calc()` compatible. Then, for browsers that are not compatible, I could use `width:33.33%` as a fallback.

My question: does placing the `width:33.33%` above or below the `width:calc(100% / 3)` make a difference in its effectiveness? Would one hierarchy work, while the other would not?

That is, would ordering my CSS properties like this:

```
div.column {
    width: 33.33%; /* Fallback in case the browser does not support calc() */

    width: -webkit-calc(100% / 3);
    width: -moz-calc(100% / 3);
    width: calc(100% / 3);
}
```

Be different than ordering them like this:

```
div.column {
    width: -webkit-calc(100% / 3);
    width: -moz-calc(100% / 3);
    width: calc(100% / 3);

    width: 33.33%; /* Fallback in case the browser does not support calc() */
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the order matters. Browsers will use the last rule they understand, so your second example would negate the calc() call for browsers that understand it.

As the [W3](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#cascading-order) states:

> ...if two declarations have the same weight, origin and specificity, the
>   latter specified wins.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it matters, "fallbacks" should be placed first.

The reason: Browsers will apply the last supported declared style only, so if for instance you have this:

```
div {
    width: 400px;
    width: 300px;
    width: 200px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

...only `100px` will apply. This is common when vendor prefixes are involved:

```
div {
    -moz-property: foo;
    property: foo;
}
```

In this case, Mozilla browsers will apply the **standard** `property` if it's supported, and fall back to the vendor specific `-moz-property` otherwise (if it's supported). The actual order of vendor prefixes does not matter, as a browser typically won't support multiple vendor prefixes.