# Grouping and Positioning list items (li)

Tags: html, css

Lets say i have the  following list:

```
<ul>
<li>item1</li>
<li>item2</li>
<li>item3</li>

<li>item4</li>
<li>item5</li>
<li>item6</li>

<li>item7</li>
<li>item8</li>
</ul>
```

And i Needed it to display like this on the webpage:

```
item1    item2    item3
item4    item5    item6
item7    item8
```

How would i accomplish this? is it easy enough to do with CSS or is there some magical PHP trick?

Ive received a few answers, but they all seem based much as my solution but it needs to take 870px and be ordered as such and also i am using bootstrap. so responsive no tables and such..

Any Help Greatly appreciated Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Woudn`t using css styling as follows be enough?

```
ul{
    width: 870px;
}
li{
    width: 33.33%;
    float: left;
}
```

870px used because author states that value in the question. This could be any other value as well.

Comment: I would add .33 to width (33.33%) for greater precision.
I think this is a better solution than l̕aͨŵƦȆ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝ƞCͭ̏ȇ ƇhƐȓ0nè's, since you would only need to tweak one value to increase/decrease number of columns.

Comment: Good point - ill change it. And that should be enough http://stackoverflow.com/a/5158996/1285871

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the width of the unordered list

```
<style>
ul{
  width: 30em;//<<<
}

ul li{
  float: left;
  width: 10em;
}
</style>
<ul>
    <li>item1</li>
    <li>item2</li>
    <li>item3</li>
    <li>item4</li>
    <li>item5</li>
    <li>item6</li>
    <li>item7</li>
    <li>item8</li>
</ul>
```

In action:http://jsfiddle.net/zsLUa/

Comment: Just change the values of the width, If you want it 870px wide, then change `width: 30em;` to `width: 870px;` and 870/3=290 so `width: 10em;` to `width:290px;`

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to display 3 items in a row, then css `:nth-child` will help:

```
li:nth-child(3n-1) {
   clear: both;
}
```

**Note: it will not work in IE8 and lower**

And here is a bit of javascript/jQuery for IE8 and IE7 support:

```
if (document.all && !document.querySelector || document.all && document.querySelector && !document.addEventListener) {
   $("li").each(function (index) {
      if (index % 4 === 0)
         $(this).css('clear', 'both');
   });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

That's really a CSS thing. Read this: http://alistapart.com/article/css-floats-101.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this page

http://d.alistapart.com/multicolumnlists/example1.html

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a html table with no borders.

Comment: Or if you want the list type follow the answer below =)

Answer (score 0):

This CSS works for me. Tweak the widths to fit your needs.

```
  ul
  {
    width: 500px;
  }

  li
  {
      display:inline-block;
      width: 160px;
  }
```

[Link to a live demo](http://scratchpad.io/B4tcnz3Yo5).

Answer (score 0):

Another solutions would go with collumns.

```
ul{
-moz-column-count:3; /* Firefox */
-webkit-column-count:3; /* Safari and Chrome */
column-count:3;
}
```