# Perfect 1/3 by percentage in css?

Tags: css, percentage, units-of-measurement

Is some solution for setting **perfect** 1/3 in % units?
width:33% is to low, 33.333% too.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5158735/best-way-to-represent-1-3rd-of-100-in-css

Comment: There will never be a "perfect" 1/3 width as long as displays have pixels.

Comment: Can you please add an example?

Comment: @Mike That's a dupe, please vote.

Answer (score 3):

Hmm.. Let browser to think on that: `calc(100% / 3)`. See [**`calc()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/calc)